# Which kernel module name is currently correct "usb-storage" or "usb_storage"?

Tags: kernel, kernel-modules, usb-drive

I have found a number of examples how to prevent a kernel module from being loaded. One of them is about USB storage module. The next code has been provided:

`echo "blacklist usb-storage" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`

then I decided to check the name by `lsmod`, so I plugged a USB stick in and found it to be different:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
usb_storage            62209  1
```

My question is: what spelling should I apply to the `blacklist`: `usb-storage` or `usb_storage`?

I have doubts about it being one name for an earlier kernel, and changed to another one for a later kernel. Currently I am running the Kernel version `3.13.0-30-generic`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The module names may contain both `-` and `_` . Both symbols can be interchanged while using with `modprobe` or `lsmod` and also in the conf files in `/etc/modprobe.d/` .

So that means you can use any of `usb_storage` or `usb-storage` for blacklisting.

Comment: Good to know, it's convenient.